# Default browser on window

Tags: windows, browser

I have a question about the default browser on Window OS. When I uninstall the current default browser, after that what is the default browser on window if I don't make default browser for other browsers?

Comment: Browser will ask you **if you want to set it as default browser** if you had more than two browsers else whatever is left will become default

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like: I have a html file. if I uninstall the default browser, after that double click this file html. what 's the browser opened this file?

Answer (score 0):

Then the default browser becomes Edge in Windows 10 or Windows Explorer in the previous Microsoft versions.

Since they are *trusted UI Apps* they cannot be uninstalled (with ordinary methods). Furthermore this is also the state of a fresh windows installation.

There still might be a prompt to set "Internet Explorer/Edge as Default Browser" when starting it the first time since the deinstallation of the prvious browser might have residues.

Comment: I'm not sure for this. Because, I just do it. sometimes, the default browser is FireFox, or Chrome or maybe IE. We can know this rule change  ?